# Custom view for NSMenuItem appearing blank

Tags: swift, macos, nsmenuitem

I've been trying to make a custom view for a NSMenuItem with an image on it. The code below overrides the original view, but without the image. The item appears blank and smaller.

This code is only an example!

```swift
class CustomItemView: NSView {
    private let imageView: NSImageView = NSImageView()
    
    override init(frame frameRect: NSRect) {
        super.init(frame: frameRect)
        
        // self.imageView.frame = frameRect
        self.imageView.image = NSImage.init(named: "example")!
        self.addSubview(self.imageView)

        self.imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            self.imageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor),
            self.imageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor),
            self.imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),
            self.imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100)
        ])
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

I then simply add set the view like this

```swift
let newItem: NSMenuItem = NSMenuItem()
newItem.view = CustomItemView()
newItem.target = self
self.addItem(newItem)
```

Comment: Be aware that you don’t call `init(frame`.

Comment: Right! I wasn't paying enough attention, it works now. Thanks @vadian